# Missing menu items for Azure SQL tables within SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: azure, ssms, sql-server-2012

I have a table (say `Table1`) that is replicated via SQL Data Sync Agent across a local SQL Server 2012 as well as an Azure SQL Server (part of Microsoft Azure). Everything about `Table1` (schema, table values etc ) is identical to the best of my understanding.

However, when I list and right click `Table1` from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (SSMS), I get some very different menu options, even for seemingly basic stuff.

Lets focus only on the 'Design' menu item:

1. It is visible for `Table1` on the local SQL server in SSMS
2. It is missing for `Table1` on Azure SQL via SSMS
3. It is visible for `Table1` (as `Open Table Definition`) on Azure SQL when reaching it via Visual Studio 2012 (Server Explorer -> Data connections)

This is seen in the screenshots below:
[image]

Now I use scripts from some real stuff (esp when I need to check in the SQL scripts etc) but this difference concerns me to some extent.

Am I witnessing just a tools artifact in SQL Server Management Studio when connecting to Azure SQL? or is it something more serious about limitations of Azure SQL itself (although, just seeing the Design surface is so basic!)?

Comment: Might check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652665/sql-server-managment-studio-missing-table-right-click-menu-options

Comment: I think that it is not the tools what's missing things.. if i connect to a sql server 2008, i would get the options mentioned. So, only with a sql azure connection, i can't use the usual options. I know, you can do all that sort of things with scripting, but it takes a lot of time extra to simply look at the table structure and change something.. So, I hope also if someone knows why this happens?!

Answer (score 1):

So, that appears to be a tools artifact. Some additional tools to help alleviate the problem at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

In regards to core Azure SQL limitations, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx shows all known limitations. The above seen issies is not listed, making it more likely it's a tools issue.